# Call ColdFusion method with explicit receiver

Tags: coldfusion, mixins, cfc, coldfusion-2016

I'm trying to write a mixin in ColdFusion.

**ExampleMixin.cfc:**

```
component {
    remote void function mixin(component, methodName) {
        var original = component[methodName];
        component[methodName] = function() {
            writeOutput("Mixin!");
            return original(arguments);
        };
    }
}
```

**test.cfc:**

```
component {
    new ExampleMixin().mixin(this, 'foo');

    remote string function foo() {
        return getOutput();
    }

    private string function getOutput() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Running `foo` produces an error, `Variable GETOUTPUT is undefined.`. If I comment out `new ExampleMixin().mixin(this, 'foo');`, it runs fine.

It looks like when `foo` is run from the wrapper, it's not running in the right context. In JavaScript, one would write `foo.call(component, ...arguments)` to rectify this. Is there an equivalent in ColdFusion?

Comment: You probably want to use inheritance (extends property of your cfc) instead. Test.cfc doesn’t do anything with the newly created instance of ExampleMixin.cfc, so nothing can be executed. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/using-cfcs-effectively.html

Comment: Inheritance is exclusive. A component might have several mixins, and it may additionally have a parent. If ColdFusion supported multiple inheritance, then it would be reasonable to implement mixins using inheritance, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: ColdFusion supports the same inheritance model as Java or C#, so: `A` can inherit from `B` can inherit from `C` can inherit from `D` etc. You can make your mixin an abstract base class and go from there. Or you can simply have all your mixin functions in a `.cfm` template that you include in your other components.

Comment: That would not allow a component to use two independent mixins, or any mixin and a parent class that does not use that mixin. Single inheritance just isn't a workable model for mixins.

Comment: Use `cfinclude` then (have every function in a separate template) and mix-in whatever your component requires. Without an actual use case, it's hard to tell if there really even is a need to use mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion uses both the `this` and `variables` scopes for storing function
references. The reference that's used depends how the function is invoked. If
the function is invoked from a sibling, the `variables` reference is used. If
the function is being invoked externally, then the `this` reference is used.

The following code uses a base class to supply the mixin functionality. The
`$mixin` function takes a component instance and injects all of its functions.
If there's a name collision a wrapper will call the mixin first, then the
original function. I'm generating new function names for both the original and
mixin functions so references can be set in both scopes.

This was tested on Lucee 5.2.8.50.

**mixable.cfc**

```
component {
    function $mixin(obj) {
        var meta = getComponentMetadata(obj);

        for(var func in meta.functions) {
            if(structKeyExists(this, func.name)) {
                var orig = func.name & replace(createUUID(), '-', '', 'all');
                var injected = func.name & replace(createUUID(), '-', '', 'all');

                this[orig] = this[func.name];
                variables[orig] = this[func.name];

                this[injected] = obj[func.name];
                variables[injected] = obj[func.name];

                var wrapper = function() {
                    this[injected](argumentCollection=arguments);
                    return this[orig](argumentCollection=arguments);
                };
                this[func.name] = wrapper;
                variables[func.name] = wrapper;
            } else {
                this[func.name] = obj[func.name];
                return variables[func.name] = obj[func.name];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**test.cfc**

```
component extends="mixable" {
    remote function foo() {
        writeOutput("foo(), calling bar()<br>");
        bar();
    }

    private function bar() {
        writeOutput("bar()<br>");
    }
}
```

**mixin.cfc**

```
component {
    function foo() {
        writeOutput("foo mixin, calling bar()<br>");
        bar();
    }

    function myfunc() {
        writeOutput("myfunc()<br>");
    }
}
```

**index.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
t = new test();
t.$mixin(new mixin());
t.myfunc();
t.foo();
</cfscript>
```

**Output**

```
myfunc()
foo mixin, calling bar()
bar()
foo(), calling bar()
bar()
```